# Meteor.js : How to get the name of a Template from the Template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

Lets say I have a definition of a template in a html file.

```
<template name="myTemplate">
```

Now in javascript I want to get the value that is name in template by referencing the Template itself to avoid typing mistakes and to allow intellij ide  ctrl clicking of the template to take me to the template.

I want something like.

```
let stringValueOfTemplateName = Template.myTemplate.name
```

Instead of having to do

```
let stringValueOfTemplateName = "myTemplate"
```

Is there any way to access the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Template.captureView.viewName.replace('Template.',''))
```

or

```
Template.instance().view.name.replace('Template.',''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let stringValueOfTemplateName = Template.instance().view.name.replace('Template.', '');
```